# Appending data to an already loaded page in vue (Facebook posts and comment)

Tags: vue.js

So i am making a Facebook-like website.
I am new to Vue and i got stuck at the comments.
I have set up a template for the posts with the like, dislike and comment buttons,
the only thing i dont know how to do is when u press the comment button i want the server responce data to be appended beneath the post and if you press it again i want the data to be hidden.Here is the template:

```
 <template>
<div class="container">
<h2> Posts</h2>
<textarea id="post" cols="50" rows="2" placeholder="Send a post" v- 
model="postBody"></textarea>
<button @click="sendPost()">Post</button>
<div class="card card-body" v-for="post in posts">
<h3>{{post.username}}</h3>
<p>{{post.postBody}}</p>
<h4>{{post.post_id}}</h4>
<small>{{post.created_at}}</small>
<span>{{post.likes}}<button @click="LikePost(post.post_id)">Like</button> 
</span>
<span>{{post.dislikes}}<button 
@click='DislikePost(post.post_id)'>Dislike</button></span>
<span>{{post.comments}}<button 
@click='ShowComments(post.post_id)'>Comment</button></span>
</div>
</div>

</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {
      posts: [],
      post: {
        id:'',
        username:'',
        postBody:'',
      },
      postBody:'',
      post_id: '',
      pagination: {},
      edit: false
    };`
```

P.S i am also new to stackoverflow so if a left any information out please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a toggle. It corresponds to a boolean data item: true is on (comments displayed) false if off (comments not displayed). The method attached to the button switches the value of the boolean. A `v-if` directive controls the display of `comments`, based on the boolean.

I've stripped your example down to just the relevant code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    comments: 'This is comments',
    commentsVisible: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComments() {
      this.commentsVisible = !this.commentsVisible;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2> Posts</h2>
  <span>
    <template v-if="commentsVisible">{{comments}}</template>
    <button @click='toggleComments'>Comment</button>
  </span>
</div>
```